# SQL missing parenthesis when creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table for a college project, but when I run my code it tells me I am missing a left parenthesis, and I simply cannot see where.

please help code is below

```
create table booking (
    booking_id number 
,   booking_ref varchar2
,   booking_date date 
,   passenger_id number 
,   travel_class_code varchar2
,   flight_id number 
,   airplane_id varchar2   compound key
,   booking_status_id varchar2   compound key
,   ticket_type_code varchar2 
,   payment_method varchar2
);
```

Comment: "compound key"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Doesn't varchar2 need a size?

Comment: I removed the sizes from varchar2 to try and find ther issue but even with only the two parenthesis at the start and end of the command I still get the error "missing left parenthesis"

Comment: Try some trouble shooting. Remove all but 1 column, can you run the statement? If so add one or more columns back? Does it run now? Do that until you find the line (column) that is causing the error. If the error occurs even with one column then there is something else going on. Learning how to trouble shoot can help you solve these problems as they arrise instead of needing to post them on SO which will slow down your development velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need sizes on the `VARCHAR2` data types and compound key is not valid.

```
create table booking (
    booking_id number 
,   booking_ref varchar2(1)
,   booking_date date 
,   passenger_id number 
,   travel_class_code varchar2(1)
,   flight_id number 
,   airplane_id varchar2(1)
,   booking_status_id varchar2(1)
,   ticket_type_code varchar2(1) 
,   payment_method varchar2(1)
,   CONSTRAINT BOOKING__PK PRIMARY KEY (airplane_id, booking_status_id)
);
```